# Cannot import Vue Component in Jest Test

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

Im trying to write my first test in Jest and cannot make my configuration run with a Vue Component.

In my Laravel Project I installed the needed npm packages with following commands:

```
npm install -—save-dev jest vue-jest jest-serializer-vue
npm install @vue/test-utils
```

In my package.json i have following configurations:

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test" : "jest"
}

...

"jest": {
    "testRegex": "tests/Javascript/.*.spec.js$"
},
```

My test is in the given Directory "root/tests/Javascript/Mytest.spec.js".

My test looks like this:

```
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils';

// If this is removed it works....
import MyVuePage from './../../resources/js/pages/MyVuePage.vue';

describe('Something', () => {
    it("Awesome", () => {
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

I get following Error:

> Jest encountered an unexpected token
>
> This usually means that you are trying to import a file which Jest cannot parse, e.g. it's not plain JavaScript.
>
> By default, if Jest sees a Babel config, it will use that to transform your files, ignoring "node_modules".
>
> Here's what you can do:
>       • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
>        • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
>        • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with >the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

In the Console there is a little Arrow Pointing on my "i" of "import SeriesVersion from './../../resources/js/pages/MyVuePage.vue';"

I run the test by writing "npm run test" into the console.

Can you tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Do you have a Babel config?

Comment: I dont have babel in my DevDependencies, but i have this in my package.json:

"babel": {
        "presets": [
            [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                {
                    "useBuiltIns": "usage",
                    "corejs": 3,
                    "targets": {
                        "chrome": "58",
                        "ie": "11"
                    }
                }
            ]
        ]
    },